# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$. Let $V^{\star}$ be the dual space of $V$. Show $V\cong V^{\star}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Question: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$.  Let $V^{\star}$ be the dual space of $V$.  Show $V\cong V^{\star}$.

I know this question has been asked several times, and is quite common, I am just looking for a nice direct proof.

If we let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$.  Since $V^{\star}$ is the dual space of $V$, that is $V^{\star}$ is the vector space of linear transformations $T:V\rightarrow F$, so $V\cong F^n$, since $V$ is finite dimensional over $F$ (I suppose that is where this breaks, because if $V$ is not finite dimensional, then we can't say this).  So, we would be done if we showed that $V^{*} \cong F^n$.
Define $T:V^{\star}\rightarrow F^n$ by $T(x^{\star})=(x^\star(v_1),\dots,x^{\star}(v_n))$.  So, we need to show that this map is an isomorphism.

$T$ is a homomorphism: $T(x^\star+y^\star)=T(x^\star)+T(y^\star)$ (I can't quite think of why I can justify this) and $T(kx^\star)=kT(x^\star),$ since $T$ is linear.

How would I go about showing that $T$ is surjective and injective?  I think I can show that $T$ is injective, because if $T(x^\star)=T(y^\star)$
, then $x^\star(v_i)=y^\star(v_i)$, for all $i$ since $x^\star$ and $y^\star$ would agree on the same basis, thus $x^\star=y^\star$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: By linear independence of the $v_i$, you can define a linear functional $x^*:V\to F$ such that $x^*(v_i)$ is any value in $F$ you want for each $i$.

Comment: @User I think that the simplest argument to make is as follows. Two (finite-dimensional) vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if their dimensions are equal. You have constructed a basis of $V^*$ using a basis of $V$, illustrating that $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension. It follows that $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @BenGrossmann But I would need to show that the mapping I defined is, indeed, an isomorphism, correct?

Comment: @User7238 I realize now that you didn't find a basis of $V^*$ in your approach. Also, I missed that you are specifically looking for a "direct proof". Disregard my earlier comment

Comment: @User7238 Dave's comment gives you a way to show surjectivity.

Comment: Yep! Thank you, Dave!  I'm sure it is something dumb I am overlooking, but how could I justify the homomorphism part?

Comment: @ArcticChar I saw that question, but I was just hoping to see it done in, I suppose, different notation, or see any alternative ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi, \psi \in V^{*}$ and $\lambda \in F$.  Then $$\begin{aligned}T(\varphi+\lambda\psi) &= ((\varphi+\lambda\psi)(v_1), \cdots, (\varphi+\lambda\psi)(v_n)) \\ &=(\varphi(v_1) + \lambda\psi(v_1), \cdots, \varphi(v_n) + \lambda\psi(v_n)) \\ &
= (\varphi(v_1), \cdots,\varphi(v_n))+(\lambda\psi(v_1), \cdots,\lambda\psi(v_n)) \\&= T(\varphi) + \lambda T(\psi)\end{aligned}  $$

hence $T$ is linear. Given any $a = (a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in F^n$, define $g: V \to \mathbb{R}$ by putting $g(v) = \lambda_1a_1 + \cdots +\lambda_n a_n$, for each $v = \lambda_1v_1 + \cdots \lambda_n v_n \in V$ (of course, the $\lambda_i$ will depend on $v$, but this doesn't matter). Then it's clear that $g(v_i) = a_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, therefore $T(g) = a$ (the motivation to choose $g$ like this comes from the fact that a linear map is uniquely determined by the values it assumes on a basis). By the arbitrariness of $a$ it follows that $T$ is surjective. Since you already showed it is injective, we conclude that $T$ is a isomorphism, as desired (here I used that a bijective linear map between vector spaces is necessarily an isomorphism, which is easy to prove).